# Why the need for user ID in ticket AND authenticator (Kerberos)?

Tags: kerberos

I am currently learning about Kerberos.

Why the following in Kerberos v4:
Client -> Service : Ticket_Service || Authenticator_Client
where Ticket_Service: E(K_S, [K_C,S || ID_C || ...])
and Authenticator_Client : E(K_C,S), [ID_C || ...])

Why is ID_C in both ticket and authenticator? I guess it is to authenticate the ticket (that it is for the correct user) but I can not think of any possible attack or problems without sending the ID of the client in both messages.